# given two continuous functions, can I prove the inequality $||fg|| \le ||f|| ||g||$ using triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

Let $f,g : [0,1] \to $ R be continuous functions.

show that $||fg|| \le ||f||||g||$.

So what I know and found out :

The absolute value is a particular instance of the norm. So, $||x||= |x|$

Suppose I take -

$f(x)=5$ and $g(x)=2$ be continuous for all x $\in[0,1]$

Then

$|f(x)|=|5| $ and $|g(x)|=|2|$

$|fg|=|5\times2|=|10|=10$

$|f||g|=|5||2|=5\times2=10$

hence, $|fg|=|f||g|$,  and  from $||x||= |x|$,

we get : $||fg||=||f||||g||$

but how do I proof ? $||fg||<||f||||g||$. Am I to use triangle inequality ?

Comment: Is $\Vert f \Vert $ the supremum norm?

Comment: thanks for the response. @MartinR I am not sure, I don't have a note which says that. What happens if it is?

Comment: @MartinR, am I to assume $||f||$ to be the supremum norm and $||g||$ to be the infimum norm?. so taking $||f||=1$ and $||g||=0$

Comment: @Ninja I do not think it is wise to use the same notation for two different norms. If this is an exercise, I am pretty sure they are the same norm.

Comment: Hey @Gary thanks for the response. I will look into it.